# how to send data using post ajax and get it from a symfony controller

Tags: ajax, symfony

Hi im trying to dend data to my method in the controller using an ajax script :

```
$("#form_enr").submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); 

    var ev = $("#mySelect").val();
    var text =$("#form_Text").val();

    console.log(text);
    console.log(ev);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ path('invitation_enregistrerInv')}}",
        data : 'ev=' + ev + '&text=' + text,
        success: function(data){
            $('.portlet-body').html(data);        
        }
    });    

});
```

and to get it I use this syntax :

```
public function enregistrerInvAction()
{
    $inv = new Invitation();    
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $request = $this->get('request');

    $ev = $request->request->get('ev');
    $text = $request->request->get('text');
      
    $inv->setCreatedAt(new \Datetime());
    $inv->setUpdatedAt(new \Datetime());
    $inv->setText($text);
       
    $em->persist($inv);
    $evenement=$em->getRepository('EvEvenementBundle:Evenement')->findById($ev);
    $evenement=new Evenement();
    $evenement->setInvitation($inv);
    $em->persist($evenement);
    $em->flush();
    $this->addFlash(
        'success',
        'Les informations ont été enregistrées!'
    );

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('invitation_index2')); 
}
```

but i seems not working, because I have this error :

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO invitation (created_at, updated_at, text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["2016-08-01 17:12:55", "2016-08-01 17:12:55", null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'text' ne peut être vide (null) !!!
> because text is null , and I don't get it

Comment: please use [`Request` injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#the-request-object-as-a-controller-argument) in you controllers, `'request'` in the container has been [deprecated in favor of the `'request_stack'`](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack)

Comment: I tried not only your suggestion but many others , it seems to be a serious problem

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you pass your `data` wrong in js side. Try to change `data` to this:

```
$.ajax({
   (...)
    data : {
        ev: ev,
        text: text
    }
});
```

(You are using `POST` method, you don't pass arguments in query string in this method)

EDIT:

Your controller action should look like:

```
public function enregistrerInvAction(Request $request){
    (...)
    $text = $request->request->get('text');
    (...)
}
```

Are you sure that valid data is coming from request? (you can try to do `var_dump($_POST)`)

Comment: and here is one problem when using this suggestion :  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: you need to give us more details What is exactly the error? Paste whole error info

Comment: check my edit. Did you check firebug or other tool if valid request is sent to server?

Comment: think you , but look at this : Controller "Invitation\InvitationBundle\Controller\InvitationController::enregistrerInvAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$request" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one). I tried with : public function enregistrerInvAction(Request $request) and my controller give this after using :var_dump($_POST) , array (size=0)
  empty it means that I don't receive any data!!!

Comment: you need to type hint the `$request` parameter, I've updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: I think I found the problem , I work with ckeditor and the textarea is in html , so how to ignore html where sending the text??

Answer (score 0):

As described in the doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object), you can try:

```
// Better use the request passed on the controller's method signature
$request = $this->get('request');

 $ev = $request->request->get('ev');
 $text = $request->request->get('text');
```

instead of:

```
$request = $this->get('request');

$ev = $request->get('ev');
$text = $request->get('text');
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi , I tried your suggestion but it is not working :(